# Oracle: range between dates

Tags: oracle, date, range

I've table with accounts rest with following data:

```
T_ID    T_RESTDATE  T_RESTSUM   T_INCOME    T_OUTCOME   
1135782 20.04.2013  16714,31    16714,31    0
1135782 20.05.2013  33362,4     16648,09    0
1135782 20.06.2013  49179,59    15817,19    0
1135782 20.07.2013  64207,42    15027,83    0
1135782 20.08.2013  78485,35    14277,93    0
1135782 20.09.2013  92050,89    13565,54    0
1135782 20.10.2013  104939,65   12888,76    0
```

To generate range between dates i usually use following query:

```
SELECT :dateBeg+level-1 turndate
FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= :dateEnd-:dateBeg+1
```

How do I get the following result:

```
T_ID    T_RESTDATE  T_RESTSUM   T_INCOME    T_OUTCOME   
1135782 20.04.2013  16714,31    16714,31    0
1135782 21.04.2013  16714,31    16714,31    0
1135782 22.04.2013  16714,31    16714,31    0
1135782 23.04.2013  16714,31    16714,31    0
...
1135782 20.05.2013  33362,4     16648,09    0
1135782 21.05.2013  33362,4     16648,09    0
1135782 22.05.2013  33362,4     16648,09    0
...
```

Comment: Do you want to order by T_RESTDATE asc?

Comment: order is not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a set of dates starting from the minimum to maximum and then outer join it with your table.
Then, Use LAST_VALUE function to fill the null values.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fee44/6)

```
create table mytab(
    t_id number,
    t_restdate date,
    t_restsum varchar2(20)
    );

insert into mytab values(1135782, date'2013-04-20', '16714,31'); 
insert into mytab values(1135782, date'2013-05-20', '33362,4');  
insert into mytab values(1135782, date'2013-06-20', '49179,59');
```

**Query 1**:

```
with x(min_date, max_date) as (
  select min(t_restdate), max(t_restdate)
  from mytab
  ),
y(all_date) as (
  select min_date + level - 1
  from x
  connect by min_date + level - 1 <= max_date
  )
select last_value(mytab.t_id) ignore nulls over (order by y.all_date),
       y.all_date,
       last_value(mytab.t_restsum) ignore nulls over (order by y.all_date)
from y left outer join mytab
on y.all_date = mytab.t_restdate
order by y.all_date;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fee44/6/0)**

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways.

A bad way ( but sometimes needed ):

```
    select *
from   TABLE_NAME
where  TABLE_NAME.DATE in (select :DATEBEG + level - 1 TURNDATE
                           from   DUAL
                           connect by level <= :DATEEND - :DATEBEG + 1)
order  by TABLE_NAME.DATE asc;
```

A good way:

```
select *
from   TABLE_NAME
where  TRUNC(TABLE_NAME.DATE) between TRUNC(TO_DATE(:DATEBEG)) and TRUNC(TO_DATE(:DATEEND))
order  by TABLE_NAME.DATE asc;
```

Comment: But i don't have :DATEEND and :DATEBEG. This dates are in rest table